# Disable groupBox including the groupBox name in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, groupbox

I have a groupBox name "groupBox".I want to disable whole groupbox includind the name of the group box.
I am attaching the image.I hope it would clear the situation[image]

```
<GroupBox Name="groupBox"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" Header="GroupBox" IsEnabled="False">
            <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".250*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".250*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RadioButton Name="RadioBtn1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="14.63">OP1</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton Name="RadioBtn2" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="14.63">OP2</RadioButton>

            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
```

I am using **IsEnabled="False"** property. but it work only content of groupBox(Pls currect me if I am wrong!)
Now I want that the circle area should also be disable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple `Trigger` can do this for you in XAML (without any code behind):

```
<GroupBox Name="groupBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" Header="GroupBox" IsEnabled="False">
    <GroupBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Control.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value ="#FF6D6D6D" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Style>
    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".250*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".250*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RadioButton Name="RadioBtn1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="14.63">OP1</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Name="RadioBtn2" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="14.63">OP2</RadioButton>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

simply using trigger

```
<GroupBox Name="groupBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,0,0" Header="GroupBox" IsEnabled="False">
  <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition>
      </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioBtn1" Height="14.63" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">OP1
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Name="RadioBtn2" Height="14.63" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">OP2
    </RadioButton>
  </Grid>
  <GroupBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="GroupBox">
      <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="header" Text="{Binding}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="header" Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
              </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </GroupBox.Style>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is not necessary to use triggers or bindings at all. You can simply use a `Label` as header (as suggested by [@progpow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20143950/3950370)) and the header will turn grey as any other control:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <Label Content="My Header Text" Padding="0" />
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

If you just assign a string to the `Header` property, WPF will use a `TextBlock` to visualize the header, but since `TextBlock` is just a `FrameworkElement` and not a `Control` like `Label`, it does not support being disabled (see [Differences between Label and TextBlock](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/)).

It is necessary to define a zero padding (`Padding="0"`) for the `Label`, because the default padding is five, which kinda looks ugly as a header of a `GroupBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change color with this:

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
      <Label Foreground="Gray">My Group Header Label</Label>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

You can change color with converters:

```
<Window.Resources>
            <local:BrushColorConverter x:Key="BConverter"></local:BrushColorConverter>
</Window.Resources>
...
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
      <Label Foreground="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BConverter}}">My Group Header Label</Label>
    </GroupBox.Header>
</GroupBox>
```

Converter code

```
 public class BrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                {
                    return System.Windows.Media.Colors.Gray;
                }
            }
            return System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```